# Code Analysis breaks due to RIA?

Tags: c#, ria, code-analysis, silverlight-5.0

```
 MSBUILD : error : CA0055 : Could not unify the platforms (mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, mscorlib, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
```

The only external libs I'm loading is RIA 1.0 SP2, and I thought that should be ok for SL5?

How can I check the assemblies to see what assembly that links to mscorlib v.2.0.5.0?

**Edit:** The RIA assemblies links with mscorlib 2.0.5.0 and I assume this is the reason for the error. Now I'm stuck with no code analysis, and that really suck. Any known workarounds for this?

Comment: Still no solution for this? Isn't static code analysis used amongst the Silverlight developers?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Reflector from RedGate, JustDecompile from JetBrains or dotPeek from JetBrains, to find the references and dependancies of a library.

Answer (score 0):

Pete Brown blogged about this issue and also provided a work-around [here](http://10rem.net/blog/2012/04/17/workaround-for-ca0055-error-with-silverlight-projects-in-visual-studio-2010).

He also referenced the related Microsoft connect bug [713608](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/713608/ca0055-silverlight5-business-application-project).

He indicates this is fixed in Visual Studio 11 RC and provides a work-around by manually running fxcop on the command line.

The Microsoft connect bug contains a work-around by modifying the project file.

Comment: The workaround from the first link worked for me.  I cheated a bit around the multiple `/d` requirement by simply using `fxcopcmd /file:[MyProjDir]\Bin\Debug\[MyDll].dll /d:[MyProjDir]\Bin\Debug /out:[TargetOutFile].xml` since the bin/debug folder had all the requisite DLLs for the project, anyway.